# Does scrum involve writing tests before code?

Tags: scrum

I just read that in XP, tests are written before code. Scrum is a different Agile Methodology but does scrum also involve writing tests before code?

Comment: What research have you done? Also, what do the abbreviations you are using mean? Not everyone uses the same abbreviation for a term or phrase.

Comment: what makes you think every "agile" system forces the use of TDD?

Answer (score 4):

> I just read that in XP, tests are written before code.

That's not what that's about. Yes, you write tests before the code, but that's a consequence, not the essence. The essence is that failing tests drive the development process, the design and the code. And in order to drive those, they obviously need to exist first.

> Scrum is a different Agile Methodology but does scrum also involve writing tests before code?

No, it doesn't. In fact, Scrum doesn't involve code *at all*. eXtreme Programming, as the name suggests, is a Methodology for Software Projects. Scrum is a Methodology for Projects. (More precisely: it is a Framework for creating Methodologies for Projects.) It could be a design project, a research project, an architecture project (as in "house", not "software architecture"), anything. Scrum doesn't concern itself with software *at all*.

When using Scrum for Software Development, it is very common to combine it with XP in such a way that the Project Management Practices from XP are ignored and the Software Development Practices from XP are integrated with the Project Management Practices from Scrum. IOW: whenever Scrum doesn't say anything in particular about a certain issue, you look to XP for answers.

The other way around, some teams augment XP with ideas from Scrum.

Answer (score 3):

> Scrum is a different Agile Methodology but does scrum also involve writing tests before code?

Not necessarily. Depending on your locale, writing (unit) tests first is "Test Driven Development" (TDD) or simply "Test First Development". Either way, it is an implementation detail of your development process (how you write the code), not an immutable part of your project management process (Scrum; How do you get people organized to make something *useful*).

I am not particularly familiar with XP, so cannot speak to it.